# Multiway switching questions

Tags: lighting

I have three 3 way switches wired in series with a ceiling fan in one room and a kitchen light. All the switches are in the kitchen, there is a two gang switch on one side where the main power comes in. The other switch is on the other side of the kitchen. I just installed a ceiling fan remote kit. However, the switch that controls the fan turns the kitchen light off while the fan is activated. I would like the kitchen light to stay on while controlling the ceiling fan light. It's a building code that I need a switch to control the ceiling fan. Would adding a 4 way switch solve the problem?[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: The blue wire controls the fan operation, the orange wire from the top is the incoming power supply. The yellow wire to the top is the line to the kitchen lights

Comment: Can we have photos of the insides of the other boxes involved, please?

Comment: The other switch is the three wires on the bottom. The orange wire goes to the common lug to the other switch, and the two yellow wires are the two traveler's

Comment: The photos would help far more than the description would